# C - Store float to char array and reverse

Tags: c, arrays, memory, floating-point, byte

Let's say I have this float:

```
float f;
```

And I want to store it in a char array:

```
char bytes[4];
```

And then ***reverse*** the array back to float.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Here is the code AND IT WORKS:

```
float amount = 0.01;
char array[sizeof(float)];
memcpy(array, &amount, sizeof(float));

float f;
char bytes[4] = {array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]};
memcpy(&f, bytes, sizeof f);
```

Comment: By “reverse” to you mean simply move the bytes from the array back to the `float` or do you mean reverse the order of the bytes, making the last byte first, the first last, and so on?

Comment: You can try with [C library function - atof()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I mean simply move the bytes from the array back to the float.

Comment: @ButiriDan I need to store it, not present it.

Comment: The code posted in the edit works for me, with `printf("%g\n", f);` appended to it (and also wrapped in `#include <stdio.h> / `#include <string.h>` / `int main(void) { … }`). It prints “0.01”.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that `sizeof(float)` is 4, you can copy the representation of the value of a `float` variable into a `char` array via `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

void do_something(float f) {
    char bytes[4];
    memcpy(bytes, &f, 4);
    // ...
}
```

You can reverse that operation (that is, copy the representation back) by calling `memcpy()` again, with the first two arguments reversed.  In between, you can manipulate the bytes -- for example, to reverse *them* -- but in that case, the language does not speak to the `float` interpretation of the resulting byte sequence.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to do what I am asking?

Comment: @evannemo, you'll have to clarify what you are asking, per the comments on your question, but if I've understood correctly what that is then I believe this answer describes exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy`, but it is good to include a `_Static_assert` to check the sizes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f = 10./7;
    char  bytes[4];

    // Check that float is the same size as the array we provide.
    _Static_assert(sizeof f == sizeof bytes, "float mus be four bytes.");

    // Copy bytes from the float to the array.
    memcpy(bytes, &f, sizeof bytes);

    // Show the bytes.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof bytes; ++i)
        printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02x.\n", i, (unsigned char) bytes[i]);

    // Copy the bytes from the array to another float.
    float g;
    memcpy(&g, bytes, sizeof g);

    // Show the resulting float.
    printf("g = %g.\n", g);
}
```

Comment: While the copy from float to char array works, the reverse doesn't work. I keep getting 0.0 at the printf.

Comment: @evannemo: The code was likely altered when you copied it. I compiled and executed before posting. And after; I copied the code from the web page and compiled and executed, and it prints “g = 1.42857.”

Answer (score 0):

- To convert float to char array `sprintf`
- To convert char array to float `atof`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char array[10];
    float val;

    sprintf(array, "%f", 3.123);
    val = atof(array);

    printf("%s\n%f", array, val);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3.123000
3.123000
```

Answer (score -2):

`memcpy` is a built-in function requiring the header "string.h". Depending on your application scenario, if you want to avoid the use of memcpy plus your char array is 4-byte aligned, here is my preferred way based on static casting in gcc-like compilers.

#### Copy amount (float) to array (char*)

```
float amount  = 0.01;
char  array[4] __attribute__((aligned(4)));
*((float *)array) = amount;
```

#### Copy bytes (char*) to f (float)

```
float f;
char bytes[4] __attribute__((aligned(4)));
f =  *((float *) bytes);
```

Alternatively, here is one more way that I believe will work under any compilers, regardless of byte alignment:

First, define a dummy struct with four bytes (a float takes four bytes. or alternatively, use sizeof(float) in place of 4).

```
typedef struct {char fourBytes[4]; } FourBytes ;
```

Use it as follows:

```
float amount     = 0.01;
char  array[4]  ;

// copy from amount to array
*((FourBytes *)array) = *((FourBytes *) (&amount));

// copy from array to amount
 *((FourBytes *) (&amount)) = *((FourBytes *)array) ;
```

From a functional perspective, a third alternative may be just to use a union structure:

```
union DATA
{
    float f;
    char  array[4];
}; // array is forced to 4-byte aligned
```

Use it as follows:

```
union DATA data1;
union DATA data2;

// copy data between the two
data1.f = data2.f
```

Comment: And that specifically is **invalid**. Your cast has undefined behaviour, due to possible unaligned access and strict aliasing violation - the correct way is to use either a loop or a `memcpy`. The compiler knows how to optimize `memcpy` away if it can.

Comment: You are definitely right. The char array should be 4-byte aligned. A strict aliasing violation warning will be issued. I still keep the answer here and just in case, it may be relevant in some scenarios, yet with the caveats in mind